# Position and offset of every selected elements returns zero always

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get position of the cursor in the element so I can get easily cursor position on the screen but I can't get real offset or position

```
alert(event.pageX +" "+
    JSON.stringify($(this).offset())
    +" "+
    JSON.stringify($(this).position())
);
```

this returns correct X of the cursor and **zeroes in left and top offset and position** of the element, which is incorrect.

Is there any simple solution for this? Is this a common problem?

Comment: Neither `offset()` nor `position()` gets the position of the mouse in the element, it gets the elements position according to the window.

Comment: I know, when I have position on the screen of the cursor and I substract position of the element on the screen I'll get position in it.

Comment: Yea, so what's the problem?

Comment: position of the given element returned by jquery is incorrect

Comment: Share the correct code, your `$(this)` is not the correct scope I guess

Comment: I tried to select it by class like this $(".hour-g3-18") but the effect is the same, and I can change css of those elements on this select so I guess it's correct